# JSON object length is returning a big value instead of expected 750 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to append records to my table which are being loaded from an AJAX request which returns JSON, but if I try to use `output.length` it returns a big number instead of 750 records. This causes the `for` loop to be run for 10000 times instead of 750. Why is this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            action: 'getData'
        },
        url: "api/ajaxcall.php",
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output.length);
            // buildTable(result);
        }
    });
}

function buildTable(output) {
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(output[i].naam),
            $('<td>').text(output[i].perc),
            $($('<input id="' + output[i].id + '" onclick="editData(this)" type = "button" value = "Edit" />')),
            $($('<input id="' + output[i].id + '" onclick="readData(this)" type = "button" value = "Read" />')),
            $($('<input id="' + output[i].id + '" onclick="deleteRow(' + output[i].id + ')" type = "button" value = "Delete" />'))
        ).appendTo('#tableA');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `dataType` is incorrect. The length is probably the length of the JSON _string_.

Comment: *Never* use `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice. You should also look in to using delegated event handlers over `on*` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this probably

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
    data: {
        action: 'getData'
    },
    url: "api/ajaxcall.php",
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(output) {
        output = JSON.parse(output.d); //May it need to parse the string
        console.log(output.length);
        // buildTable(result);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Or change the "dataType" to "json"